# Differences between REST and JSON APIs

Tags: android, json, api, rest

Wondering what the differences between REST and JSON APIs are, how you interface with them, and how to go about parsing the results. My goal is to build a small application for my android phone to tell me when the next train will get to the subway station by my house, using the developer API provided by the transit agency.

I'm learning C++ in university, but hope to go about this in Java. I'm sorry if this is more of a discussion question rather than a black and white answer question, but I can't find any information elsewhere.

[APIs in Question](http://developer.wmata.com/)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend doing some basic searching on REST and JSON APIs. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rest+vs+json+api (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Comment: I tried the Wikipedia solution, didn't work too well for me, but I'll try searching Stack Overflow better next time. Sorry, but it seemed like nothing else was working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Very first thing to mention, JSON is not an API but a data format webservices and programs use to communicate to each other.

Webservices can be of many forms but most popular are REST and SOAP. Webservices give you a way to interact with remote machines and communicate with them.

To read more about Json, visit http://www.json.org/ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

And to read more about Webservices, visit, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservices

Comment: @MaxDesyatov this question predates jsonapi.org specification.